# I want to format my timepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using trent richardson's timepicker and I want to format my time so it looks like this below:

> 00 Hrs 00  Mins 00 Secs

At the moment my time format code is this: `timeFormat:'hh:mm:ss',` which displays `00:00:00`

Now I tried `timeFormat:'hh Hours mm Mins ss Secs',` but it displays this `00 Hr0 00 Min0 00 Sec0`.

This is because `'s'` in the time Format code is part of seconds so it will display 0.

So for me to be able to format the time to the way  i want it, is there a way I can use concatenation to join the time format and strings together? for example `timeFormat:'hh' + Hrs + 'mm' + Mins ...` for example, or do I have to hack into js source code and change 's' ans 'ss' to something else. I don't really want to hack into js file because then it will make the code seem bit meaningless (for example if I change `'s'` to `'q'`, if someone reads q they won't know what it means).

Thanks

timepicker website is here if you want to look at it: [click here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with a bit of hard work I may have found a solution.

In the addon file replace lines 856 to 860 by this code :

```
case 'hh': return ('0' + hour).slice(-2)+' hours';
case 'h':  return hour;
case 'mm': return ('0' + time.minute).slice(-2)+' Mins';
case 'm':  return time.minute;
case 'ss': return ('0' + time.second).slice(-2)+' Secs';
```

In your JS set the timeFormat to "hh mm ss"... and it should it work !

Carefull though... You'll always have the "Hours", "Mins" and "Secs" appearing !!

Comment: That was worked, thank you so much with your help, greatly appreciate the time and effort you have put helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to escape the 's' that is causing the problem. jQuery's escape sequence is the double \ however I am not sure if that's the same for the time format on this date picker.
The new format code would look like:

```
timeFormat:'hh Hour\\s mm Min\\s ss Sec\\s'
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this did not work, it does not let me oen up timepicker if I include this. but strangley enough it gives me error stating: unmatched ) in regular expression on line 252 which is strange

Comment: @user1096866 that is not so strange. If you look at the 252nd line on the plugin file, you'll see that it uses regex to compose the format you want. I think you'll have to change the code directly in the plugin to achieve what you want !

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was line 252 in my file, I will have a look at the jsfile

Comment: Could concatenation work like I mentioned in my question or is this not possible?

Comment: @user1096866 I'm not a regex expert so I'm not the best person to help you on that... but I'm pretty sure that deleting it is not the right way to do that indeed. ;) Let me check...

Comment: Sorry I didnt have time to impliment that specific plugin anf wasnt sure how exactly they were implementing the format string. I sadly assumed they would follow jQuery syntax. You know what they say about assuming...